# Jquery table get total

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have writen an function to get the totals of certain rows.

The function works ok, but I have one problem It does not count the rows which are filtered/selected on the table change but all the rows.

I don't know how that can be because when I look in the html source, only 5 rows are there and the functions counts all 25 rows before the filter.

Jquery :

```
$("#mainTable").change(function(){  
    var element = $(this),
    footer = element.find('tfoot tr'),
    dataRows = element.find('tbody tr'),
    initialTotal = function () {
        var column, total;
        //for (column = 1; column < footer.children().size(); column++) {
            for (column = 3; column < 4; column++) {

            total = 0;
            dataRows.each(function () {
                var row = $(this);
                total += parseFloat(row.children().eq(column).text());
            });
            footer.children().eq(column).text(total);
        };
    };
    initialTotal();
});
```

Example page :

/

As you can see when you select "PARTIJ" 0/1/2 it executes the count function and gives total but total for all rows and not only the selected "PARTIJ".

Comment: Authentication is needed when I tried to open: http://backlinker.nl/sys/

Comment: Im sorry let me check.

Comment: You can view it now.

Comment: `element.find('tbody tr:visible')`?

Comment: Sometimes it's so easy !! Thanks man.. worked like a charm.

Comment: I don't know if you're using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), but there is a [math widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-math.html) which would do this work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing line:

```
dataRows = element.find('tbody tr'),
```

to

```
dataRows = element.find('tbody tr:visible'),
```

which applies the [:visible selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)